# Difference between this and .this?

Tags: java, function, methods, reference

What is the difference between `this` and `.this` when calling functions? And, what happens when `this` or `this.` is used?

Example:

```
class reference
{
   public void object()
   {
      reference obj = new reference();
      this.obj();
   }
}
```

Comment: `.this` is not a valid expression in Java. You have ripped this out of its context.

Comment: It would be nice to see a small example of what you're referring to. I can only assume as to what context you're using these in.

Comment: You most likely mean the difference between `this` and `SomeClass.this`.

Comment: Here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Class.this` syntax is useful when you have a non-static nested class that needs to refer to its enclosing class's instance.It is only used in cases where there is an inner class, and one needs to refer to the enclosing class

Within an instance method or a constructor, `this` is a reference to the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within an instance method or a constructor by using `this`.

A good example

```
   public class TestForThis {

    String name;
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    class TestForDotThis {
        String name ="in";
        String getName() {
            return TestForThis.this.name;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestForThis t = new TestForThis();
        t.setName("out");
        System.out.println(t.getName());
        TestForThis.TestForDotThis t1 = t.new TestForDotThis();
        System.out.println(t1.getName());
    }
}
```

Output will be

```
out
out
```

Comment: Just a small note: "non-static nested" (or simply "inner") does not imply "has an enclosing instance".

Comment: Oh. So the .this syntax is used only when the class has to refer to another's class' instance, whereas, the this syntax is used for the object currently calling the method/constructor, right?

Comment: Ok, I'm am beginning to understand this. But, can you add some comments for better understanding? I would really appreciate your help!